# How to authenticate with Dockerhub using Drone CI on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, authorization, dockerhub, drone.io

Since November 2nd Dockerhub is enforcing a limit on pulls from their registry. My Drone CI publish (to a private registry) is failing because it's based on openjdk:14-jdk-alpine which has to be pulled from a registry.

So I created an account on https://hub.docker.com/ and configured the config.json as below

My /root/.docker/config.json looks like this

```
{
    "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                    "auth": "my-api-key-is-here"
            }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
            "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/19.03.13 (linux)"
    }
```

}

So I have the following containers running:

```
drone/drone:latest
drone/drone-runner-docker:latest
```

where the drone-runner-docker has a volume bind to the host for the docker sock (/var/run/docker.sock)

When running the build and publish I'm receiving the toomanyrequests error below.

```
toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by 
authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
time="2020-11-20T22:50:14Z" level=fatal msg="exit status 1"
```

Apparently I'm still in guest-mode, what am I doing wrong?

```
latest: Pulling from plugins/docker
Digest: 
sha256:60f36379eb3f1b27a61f7c0a275dd260387a00af1144345976475b2a35e5ee4f
Status: Image is up to date for plugins/docker:latest
+ /usr/local/bin/dockerd --data-root /var/lib/docker -- 
host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Registry credentials or Docker config not provided. Guest mode enabled.
```

Comment: You found a solution for this ?